# container ViewController with scrolling ViewControllers

Tags: ios, scrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm searching for ideas for scroll containing ViewControllers. I need know the position of containing view controllers.
I've already tried UIPageViewController but I cant get scrolling delegate to work.
I also don't want to add views of viewController to scroll because its not good solution.
I'm looking for ideas and examples

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the result that you want to obtain, but seems like you want to manage more then one UIViewController and sisplay the related view in the same, let's say "contentView"...
if is this the case, you can actually have a main viewcontroller and 'addChildViewController' to the it, yes this is also the name of the method, in this way you can add the view of each viewcontroller to the view of the main view controller, and the life cycle of the childs is owned by the father. I made it simple, but this is just an idea that you can work on. I hope this is helpful for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the scrollView of the pageViewController, and you should use UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll style.

```
for (UIView *view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView*)view setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```